# Angular 2 - Countdown timer switching from minutes to seconds?

Tags: angular, rxjs, countdowntimer

I have a timer that starts from 5 minute (not displaying seconds). When it reaches to 1 minute, how do i switch it seconds?

Example: 5 minute, 4 minute, 3 minute, ..., 1 minute, 60 seconds, 59, 58, ..., 0.

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
import { take, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: `<h2>{{countDown | async}} minute</h2>`
})
export class App {
   countDown;
   countInMinutes = 5;
   countInSeconds = 60;

   constructor() {

       this.countDown = timer(0,60000).pipe(
          take(this.countInMinute),
          map(()=> --this.countInMinute)
       );

       this.countDown = timer(0,1000).pipe(
          take(this.countInSec),
          map(()=> --this.countInSec)
       );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, let's just use a single timer with second precision. To display this value, there's a bunch of different ways. We'll choose to create our own pipe for this:

```js
@Pipe({
  name: "timeRemaining",
})
export class TimeRemainingPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number) {
    if (value <= 60) {
      return `${value} seconds`;
    }

    const minutesRemaining = Math.ceil(value / 60);
    return `${minutesRemaining} minutes`;
  }
}
```

We can now write a simple component like this (modify to your liking, your question was about the display):

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-countdown",
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="!!timerSub">{{ value | timeRemaining }}</div>
    <button (click)="startTimer()" [disabled]="!!timerSub">Start</button>
  `,
})
export class AppCountdownComponent implements OnDestroy {
  public timerSub: Subscription;
  public value: number;

  public startTimer() {
    // For demonstration purposes
    const startValue = 1 * 60 + 5;

    this.timerSub = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
      take(startValue + 1),
      map(value => startValue - value)
    ).subscribe(
      value => this.value = value, 
      null, 
      () => this.timerSub = null
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.timerSub) {
      this.timerSub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

[Here's a Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-itki8f) where you can see it in action.

Comment: How would i stop a timer?

Comment: if a header button is clicked, how do i stop the timer? and if i closed the pop-up, how to resume?

Comment: You can stop it by calling unsubscribe early. Pausing and resuming is something for which you should ask a new question. This one is about displaying it. And if the answer solves that question, please mark it as accepted and consider upvoting it.